# query with IN clause fails on the second run with custom query & setParameter in spring-data-jpa 3.0.0 and hibernate 6.1.5Final

Tags: spring, hibernate, spring-data-jpa

Query with IN clause failson the second run, if we have a custom query and we set the parameter to it.

Spring data JPA 3.0.0
Hibernate Version 6.1.5

As you can see from the log below the same query is generated by querydsl. And fails on the second run with java.lang.AssertionError.

[image: 1]

Trying to update the spring latest with custom Query with In clause, But not working properly.

Comment: Try updating to Hibernate 6.1.7 or 6.2.0.CR2, and if you still have the problem, please create an issue in the issue tracker(https://hibernate.atlassian.net) with a test case(https://github.com/hibernate/hibernate-test-case-templates/blob/master/orm/hibernate-orm-6/src/test/java/org/hibernate/bugs/JPAUnitTestCase.java) that reproduces the issue.

Comment: Tried with 6.1.7 & 6.2.0 
6.1.7: Test case passes but fails when tried with List<Objects>
6.2.0: Does not work well with Jakarta Throws error related to Jakarta.